# Повелительное от "лечь"

Tags: глаголы

Словари говорят, что "ляг", но в устной речи (а также в форумах и т.д.) мне встречалось чаще всего "ляжь".

Не устарели ли словари (капитан Очевидность напоминает, что любой язык эволюционирует), или по каким правилам нужно именно "ляг"?

Comment: If I remember correctly, in Moscow it was improper(неграмотно/old school) to use "ляг/ляжь".
Mоскаль(Moscowvite) would probably say лечь/ложись/ложиться. But I've heard both: ляг(correct), and ляжь(which is wrong)

Comment: @JamaDjafarov "Лечь" is infinitive. Using infinitive instead of imperative in Russian is not a dialect, but a perfectly legal construction. Yet there is one point: it _always_ means a strong order.

Comment: @user4419802 the question was not about imperative use of the infinitive

Comment: @Viridianus I know. Re-read both comments above.

Answer (score 4):

Никогда не встречал "ляжь", вот даже как образчик ne plus ultra бескультурной речи, каким он бесспорно являлся бы. Просто не встречал и всё тут.

Comment: гуглём легко находится: ляжь на диван, ляжь в постель и т.д.

Comment: @user31264 Для этого понадобится искать. Попробуйте представить себя на моем месте: приходит человек и по поводу формы, которую я слышу первый раз, говорит "не устарели ли словари?".

Comment: Вы узнали, что форму, которую вы не слышали, другие считают правильной.

Comment: @user31264 да, узнал. И теперь в отдельном шоке от собственно  формы.

Comment: Что ещё ужаснее, "ляжь" встречается и у классиков: "И хоть спину тут в работе переломи, хоть животом ляжь ― из земли еды не выколотишь, больше, чем начальничек тебе выпишет, не получишь." (Солженицын, "Один день Ивана Денисовича");  "Ляжь ты, окаян-на-я! Что ты себя мордуешь?" (Шолохов, "Тихий Дон"); "Ляжь, как надо, а то ишь разбросался!" (А. Гайдар "Судьба барабанщика") (а также Катаев, Платонов, Пастернак, Короленко).  Правда, во всех случаях это речь персонажей.

Comment: @user31264 Ну, что-то сродни *ездиет*, которое одно время, казалось, шло победным маршем. Я слишком все-таки бурно, пожалуй, отреагировал, извиняюсь. В основном от неожиданности. Если вдуматься, я сам не очень понимаю, откуда взялась повелительная форма *ляг*.

Comment: Всегда встречал только "ляжь". "Ляг" звучит как какой-то диалектизм или неграмотность (если бы я это услышал в устной речи, подумал бы, что это какой-то глагол прошедшего времени). Я тоже в шоке, что словари считают это правильным.

Comment: Встречалось (да и сам порой употребляю) и то, и другое. Но привык думать, что единственная литературно-правильная форма "ляг". Удивлен, что тут есть сомнения.

Comment: @user31264 _>Правда, во всех случаях это речь персонажей_
У Цветаевой встречается и в авторской речи:

_Ненависть, - чти
Смертную блажь!
Ненависть, спи:
Рядышком ляжь!_

Но у поэтов вообще свои представления о языке.

Answer (score 2):

"Ляг(те)" является единственной нормативной формой.
Распространение некорректного "*ляжь(те)" связано с тем, что "ляг(те)" - единственное исключение из правила, по которому для образования повелительного наклонения без суффикса "-и" окончание отсекается от формы второго лица: "встань(те)" от "встанешь" (не "встан(те)" от "встану").
Тем не менее, словари не устарели, и "ляг" остаётся достаточно частотным.

Comment: Если "ляг" - исключение из правила, да ещё единственное, то его правильность действительно может быть основана только на частотности, на чём же ещё.  Но "ляжь" - тоже вполне себе частотное. Получается, что есть две формы повелительного наклонения.  И да, логично образовывать повелительное наклонение от 2 лица будущего времени, а там у глагола `лечь`  "ж", а не "г".

Comment: Именно: форма "*ляжь(те)" была бы логичной. Однако здесь, как с глаголом "звонить" и некоторыми другими формами, норма проявляет потрясающую упёртость (если что, форму "*звОнит" я, пока не приехал из Петербурга в Москву, слышал только в контексте предписания не говорить так, в быту все, кто окружал меня, говорили "звонИт", как и предполагает норма).

Answer (score 1):

http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ushakov/849810 в толковом словаре Ушакова - действительно "ляг"

В разговорной речи редко употребляется повелительное от "лечь". Чаще говорят "ложи(те)сь", но это уже глагол "ложиться". 8)

"Ляг" иногда слышу, но нечасто.

Всю жизнь в Москве, "Ляжь" я не слышал **никогда**.

Касаемо "словари устарели - не устарели": разговорная речь вообще имеет не так много общего с классическим языком, причём любым: и русским, и иностранным. 15 лет учил английский только для того, чтобы понять, что там никто не говорит по классическим канонам грамматики. Учил, чтобы потом принудительно разучиваться 8) . В русском языке аналогичная ситуация, и это нормально до некоторых пределов.

Comment: В русском языке аналогичной ситуации скорее нет. Расхождения, особенно не связанные с фонетикой, между нормативным и разговорным русским языком по сравнению с французскими или английскими незначительны. Это может быть связано с тем, что и диалектных нефонетических различий на русскоговорящей территории, кроме южного -ть вместо -т в окончаниях глаголов, особенно нет (о лексике тоже речь, естественно, не идёт).

Answer (score 0):

Первое же впечатление, что "ляжь" - просто форма разговорная просторечная по образу "лОжить". Хотя и "ляг" для меня звучит неудобно, если можно так выразиться. Мысленно я могу представить, что я скажу, например, ребёнку "Ляг уже". Но скорее я бы использовал "ложись".
Но, отвечая на сам вопрос, моё мнение, что ляжь - неграмотно. Если бы надо было выбрать из двух вариантов - однозначно выбрал бы "ляг".
Да вот хотя бы представить себе ситуацию - во время войны при звуке подлетающей бомбы - какое слово хочется употребить - "Ляг", "ляжь" или "ложись"?

Comment: Ну "встань уже" тоже как-то коряво звучит. Лучше "вставай уже". Точно так же и "ляг" и "ложись".

Comment: "Встань рядом со мной" и "Вставай рядом со мной" - обе формы вполне себе нормально звучат для меня. Первое более повелительное, второе скорее просьба-предложение. А вот для ляг и ложись такого ощущения нет.

Comment: Ну так и "ляг рядом со мной" и "ложись рядом со мной" нормально звучат. А для "(сделай что-то) уже" разница более ощутима в обоих случаях.

Answer (score 0):

Вроде как "ляг". Ляг на спину.

Answer (score 0):

ИМХО в данном случае словари не устарели, слова `ляг` и `лягте` употребляются не на столько реже, чем `ляжь` и `ляжьте`.
Думаю, что во мн.ч. правильная форма даже преобладает

Comment: К несчастью, ошибки в вашем ответе подрывают доверие к вашим словам.

Comment: Давайте их тоже внесем в правила, ведь "любой язык эволюционирует" (с)  :)

Comment: Вот когда эти ошибки будет считать нормой значительная часть носителей языка, тогда и внесём.

Answer (score 0):

"ложи[те]сь"

Гораздо более частотная форма без грамматической неопределённости.

Comment: Это не форма глагола "лечь".

Comment: Я к тому, что "ляг" и "ляжь" желательно вообще не употреблять.

Comment: "Ляжь" употреблять однозначно не стоит. "Ляг" — только если сильно бояться оступиться. С "ложись" оно не взаимозаменимо, "ложись" на его фоне может звучать резко.

Comment: "Ложитесь" достаточно вежливо звучит. Тогда как "лягте" или "ляжьте" ещё даже хуже и сложнее выбор.

Comment: Там нет никакого выбора. Как между "кладите" и "ложьте".

Comment: Нет, не как между "кладите" и "ложьте".